# Interest of debt

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Debt payments of $2,950$ and $1,600$ are due in five months and nine months respectively. What single payment is required to settle both debts in one month, assume a simple interest rate of $5.80\%$ p.a. and use one month from now as the focal date ?

Answer (score 0):

Let $P$ be the payment in one month. It is determined by,

$$\frac{P}{1+\frac{r}{12}}= \frac{2950}{1+\frac{5r}{12}}+ \frac{1600}{1+\frac{9r}{12}}$$

with $r=0.058$